# A suggested edit that "corrects" error messages alongside other improvements

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, specific-edit

While reviewing, I saw a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23203053) that is pretty good - improves the grammar and spelling of the post and overall makes the question better.

However, it also touched on the error messages cited in the question. Just to be completely clear, the change was from

```
WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud` not in system PATH.
```

to

```
WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud` not in the system PATH.
```

There is a few instances where it's the same - a grand total of **the** added before **system PATH**.

It's a superfluous change but somehow it doesn't sit right with me. My immediate concern is that it makes it harder to search for this. Which might not really be a concern if you use a search engine, as people would paste the message without **the** and would still find this. Still, I feel like error messages should very strictly follow citing rules and not be altered.

I am not sure how to handle this, so I'm asking for advice here - how *should* such cases be handled?

- Approve - I personally couldn't justify clicking it but I can understand this stance. It's a clear improvement of the question and the error messages are altered.
- Reject - seems too minor of a point to reject an edit over and it ultimately leaves the post in a worse state.
- Improve Edit - possibly the step to make. It's an "Approve, but..." and then edit the error messages back.
- Reject and Edit - another possibility. This one is an "No, instead use..." but then you'd have to make the same edits as before.

Basically, I believe one of the last two was warranted but I'm not sure which one sends the more appropriate message overall. I ended up skipping the review and asking here instead.

Comment: It is notable that a lot of apps localize their error messages these days.  Big problem, the user's hand-translated English version is not often a good match.  But sure, this one wasn't.  And not a big problem.  Just edit it, easy peasy.

Comment: As you said rest of the edit is valuable, `Improve Edit` look best option.

Comment: So far, it doesn't seems the community is as split about this as me. There is a single answer in favour of "Reject and Edit" sitting at +10/-0, however, there are also comments in favour of "Improve edit". The suggested edit itself has already passed and one reviewer rejected it, while two others approved it. I've went and edited back the error messages afterwards yet it doesn't really seem like a very clear cut issue with people seemingly being on both sides of it.

Comment: I'll wait for more potential answers before accepting any, as there is a single one. Nobody has made an answer in favour of Improve Edit, so I don't think it's very fair to accept the single answer on something with clear arguments for both sides.

Comment: You know you don't *have* to accept any answer, right? And you can self-answer...

Comment: @HereticMonkey well, at the moment the Reject and Edit options seems like the more correct thing to me. There is already an answer for that effect but it seems a bit daft to accept it without a real counter argument. I could, of course, not accept anything but this doesn't seem like a situation with no answer to me.

Answer (score 21):

> Still, I feel like error messages should very strictly follow citing rules and not be altered.

Indeed. Changing the error message is inappropriate, and worsens the post to a significant extent. "Reject and edit", which allows keeping the improvements while indicating the edit was problematic, is the most appropriate option, though I agree that having to manually reapply the corrections can be somewhat annoying.

(One caveat is that, [as pointed out by Mark Amery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385810/a-suggested-edit-that-corrects-error-messages-alongside-other-improvements/385812?noredirect=1#comment701862_385812), it is a good idea to Google for the error message before choosing between "Reject and edit" and "Improve edit", in order to be sure the edit was an outright mistake, and not just a case of the editor seeing a reworded error message in their environment due to a version change.)

Comment: OP said the edit *"is pretty good - improves the grammar and spelling of the post and overall makes the question better"*, thus the correct option is to improve the edit. He can ping the editor in the comments if he wants to explain why he didn't accept the specific part.

Comment: @user000001 Are you sure a ping in the comments works for editors as well?

Comment: @Tom Yes, absolutely sure, though the auto-complete feature won't work, you must type the name yourself.

Comment: @user000001 This could work too, as long as the editor is warned through a ping. Still, I do think that, on the balance of things, introducing a substantive mistake (like unduly changing an error message) carries more weight than doing formal improvements (like fixing grammar).

Comment: A caveat, based on my own past mistakes: Google both versions of the error messages first. Sometimes error messages change between versions of a program or library. That means that somebody seemingly inappropriately applying a "typo fix" to an error message may be doing so because the version they see output by their own computer doesn't have the typo, so they wrongly assume that it's misquoted in the question. Then a reviewer comes along, assumes a different motive, and rejects. Confusion results. Shortcut this whole process by Googling before acting, whether as editor or reviewer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Improve Edit"? Reject would clear the original changes whereas improve would keep them but allow the erroneous edits to be removed.

Comment: @JamesCoyle "Improve Edit" would be easier for the reviewer, but duplode is arguing, reasonably, that you should use "Reject and Edit" anyway (and do the extra work of manually reimplementing the good changes), because the edit is *on net* bad and therefore deserving of rejection. Both are defensible; I would Reject & Edit for the same reason as duplode.

Comment: @MarkAmery Does this actually make a difference under the hood? Does improve keep the original edit in the history and reject remove it or something? I figured both were basically the same but with the former keeping the changes and the latter discarding them.

Comment: @JamesCoyle Improve Edit will accept it and make another edit after. Reject and Edit will reject it, denying the +2 rep to the editor and (I assume) it could contribute to an edit ban if the user has too many rejected edits. I think they will also get a message next time they edit to the effect of "Your last edit was rejected - see why <link>".

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification. It's not really clear that this is happening and I'd assumed the only way an edit was accepted was if enough people clicked approve. "Improve edit" to me says the edit wasn't good enough to be accepted but with changes it would be and therefore only the updated edit should be accepted.

Comment: @MarkAmery (and regarding the edit) - I did google the error message but I couldn't find one that included `the system PATH` or similar. I didn't do an exhaustive search but it doesn't show up within the first page of results. I did try to search for the error message that includes `"the"`. So, it *seems* like that error message is incorrect. I can't be totally sure but if it is actually correct, it doesn't show up to a lot of people. At least not ones posting questions about it.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, in this case, a Google confirms that the edit was wrong and the version before was right. My comment was just a thing for readers to consider when encountering similar scenarios in future.

Comment: @JamesCoyle Yup. "Improve edit" is for when the edit is essentially good, even if there are minor tweaks to it that are worth doing.